# no match for 'operator*' in 'shared_data *shm' error

Tags: c++

This program is suppose to create a shared memory between a child and parent process where the child process saves into it the fibonacci sequence of a certain length (argument) and the parent process spits it out. it's also suppose to attach and detach the shared memory. Everything seems functional except for the fact that I get this error:

```
proj2.cpp:40: error: no match for 'operator*' in 'shared_data *shm' error
```

Any help? code below.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_SEQUENCE 10

struct shared_data{
    long fib_sequence[MAX_SEQUENCE];
    int sequence_size;
} shared_data;

using namespace std;

char * shm;

int Fibonacci(int n){
    int first = 0, second = 1, temp = 0;
    shared_data.fib_sequence[0] = first;
    shared_data.fib_sequence[1] = second;
    for(int i = 2; i<=n; i++){
            temp = first + second;
            shared_data.fib_sequence[i] = temp;
            first = second;
            second = temp;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    int seg_id;
    const int shd = 4096;
    seg_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, shd, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    shared_data *shm = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0); 
    int number = atoi(argv[1]);    
    if(number < 0 || number > 10){
        cout << "Invalid number. Please enter a number greater than 0 \n";
        return(1);
    }
    shared_data.sequence_size = number;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
        Fibonacci(number);
    else{
        waitpid(pid,0,0);
        for (int i = 0; i <= shared_data.sequence_size; i++)
            cout << shared_data.fib_sequence[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a struct `shared_data` and at the same time created an object of type `shared_data` with the name .... `shared_data`.

Then you create a `char*` called `shm`.

So in `shared_data *shm = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0);`, the `*` is interpreted as the binary `*` operator, trying to 'multiply' your object `shared_data` with your char pointer `shm`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
shared_data *shm = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0);
```

has the following properties:

1. `shared_data` is an object, not a type.
2. `shm` is an object that was declared earlier as well.
3. You are attempting to multiply those two variables together, and then assign to the result.

You might want something like:

```
struct shared_data *shm = shmat(seg_id, NULL, 0);
```

Or you might want to use a `typedef` in your declaration of the `shared_data` struct.

Comment: when I use typedef I get these errors across the code "expected unqualified-id before '.' token" and "expected primary-expression before '.' token"